# List of Pairs iterator in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, c++14

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    unordered_map< int,list<pair<int,int>>> adjList;
    adjList[1].push_back(make_pair(2,2));
    adjList[1].push_back(make_pair(4,-1));
    adjList[0].push_back(make_pair(1,3));
    for(pair<int,int> neighbour : adjList[1]){
        pair<int,int>* it = &neighbour;
       std::advance (it,1);
       cout<<it->first<<" ";    //1)showing random value twice instead of 4(-1113715584 -1113715584) 
    }
    for (list<pair<int,int>>::iterator i=adjList[1].begin(); i!=adjList[1].end(); i++)
        cout<<*i.first;         //2)list<std::pair<int, int> >::iterator'has no member named 'first'
    }
}
```

1. it is showing correct value(2,4) without `{std::advance (it,1);}` which is supposed to take iterator to next head but it is showing some random value twice every time.
2. > error : '`std::__cxx11::list<std::pair<int, int> >::iterator`' {aka '`struct std::_List_iterator<std::pair<int, int> >`'} has no member named '`first`'
   > `cout<<*i.first;`

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` -- Use the proper headers, not this one.

Answer (score 3):

You are invoking [undefined beahvior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) here:

```
   pair<int,int>* it = &neighbour;
   std::advance (it,1);
   cout<<it->first<<" ";
```

It is the same problem as with

```
   std::pair<int,int> p;
   std::pair<int,int>* ptr = &p;
   ptr += 1;                     // ok-ish 
   std::cout << ptr->first;      // undefined behavior !!
```

You can only increment a pointer to get a valid pointer when the pointer points to an element in an array. Incrementing the pointer to a single object is fine, because sloppy speaking a single pair can be considered as an array of size 1 and it is allowed to get a pointer one past the last element of an array. However, you shall not dereference that pointer.

A `std::list` does not store its elements in contiguous memory. You could get a pointer to an element in eg a `std::vector` and advance it to get a pointer to the next element. However, the address you are taking is actually not to the element in the list. When you write

```
for(pair<int,int> neighbour : adjList[1]){
```

Then `neighbour` is a copy of the element in the list. It is a single `pair`, completely unrelated to the `list`. If you had used

```
for(pair<int,int>& neighbour : adjList[1]){
```

Then `neighbour` would be a referece to the element in the list, but your code would still be wrong for the reasons explained above.

---

The second error is due to a typo. `*i.first` is `*(i.first)` but you want `(*i).first` or `i->first`.

---

Last, but not least, consider that `std::make_pair` has much fewer use-cases than it had before C++11. Your case isn't one of them, you can simply write:

```
adjList[1].push_back({2,2});
```

Moreover, I suggest you to read [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).